# "Si" imparfait + indicatif ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps

En parlant récemment avec un ami francophone, il m'a dit la phrase suivante :

> Je reste à votre disposition, s'il fallait des précisions.

Après, je lui ai demandé si la formulation était correcte et il m'a répondu que oui mais il ne savait pas pourquoi. Je connais déjà l[es règles de l'emploi habituel de "si" dans une clause conditionnelle](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-28092.php), mais elles ne semblent pas s'appliquer ici.

Est-ce que l'un d'entre vous aurait une explication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'imparfait utilisé ici n'a pas de valeur temporelle puisque la subordonnée (le besoin potentiel de précision) se situe manifestement dans le futur.

Le présent est utilisé dans *je **reste** à votre disposition* pour indiquer la permanence de cette affirmation. Je reste signifie : *j'étais, je suis et je continuerai à être votre disposition*.

Utiliser le conditionnel présent dans la proposition principale donnerait :

> Je resterais à votre disposition s'il fallait des précisions.

Cette forme peut être comprise comme signifiant que dans tous les autres cas possibles, je ne serais pas à votre disposition. Ceci peut être perçu comme impoli, ou du moins comme mettant une restriction forte sur la proposition de service qui peut être mal perçue.

La concordance des temps pourrait aussi faire préférer le présent dans la subordonnée :

> Je reste à votre disposition s'il faut des précisions.

Cependant, l'imparfait est légitime ici car il a une [valeur modale](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4198) et non temporelle.

> Je reste à votre disposition, s'il fallait des précisions.

Answer (score 2):

L'ambiguïté que tu soulèves (ta connaissance des subordonnées introduites par *si* qui ne semble pas s'appliquer ici) provient d'une ambivalence de cette **conjonction**.

*Si* est une conjonction de subordination qui peut introduire **deux** types de subordonnées :

- D'une part effectivement des subordonnées dites **conditionnelles**
- Mais aussi des subordonnées dites **interrogatives indirectes** (*Je me demande **si** tu comprends*)

Dans le cas d'une subordonnée conditionnelle, tu connais donc les règles, elle doivent s'appliquer sans exception et ici, nous aurions une faute au sens où le verbe de la proposition principale devrait être au conditionnel.

Dans le cas d'une *interrogative indirecte*, ce qui me semble le cas dans ton exemple, (présomption renforcée par l'usage de l'indicatif dans la principale) **c'est la règle générale de concordance des temps** qui s'applique :

verbe de la principale au présent => verbe de la subordonnée au présent, à l'imparfait ou au futur simple.

En apparence, cette phrase respecte donc la règle générale de concordance des temps et pourrait être vue grammaticalement correcte.

**Sémantiquement** parlant, c'est une toute autre affaire puisque le temps de la subordonné est à positionner en fonction du rapport dans le temps qu'entretiennent les verbes des deux propositions.

L'imparfait dans la subordonnée signifierait ici que *il te fallait des explications* **AVANT** que *je reste à ta disposition* ce que la phrase, telle que je la comprends contredit entièrement.

C'est pourquoi je tiendrai cette construction pour rigoureusement inconséquente sur le plan sémantique. Certains diront bancale. J'irais jusqu'à absurde.

EDIT : Après cela, à l'oral, on n'est pas non plus obligé d'entendre la seconde proposition en tant que proposition subordonnée. Et, dans ce cas on pourrait très bien considérer l'expression de deux phrases simples ne posant pas le moindre problème sur le plan de la correction :

Je reste à ta disposition **.** (point)
S'il fallait des explications...

Answer (score 1):

La construction ne se trouve pas à la [référence citée dans la question](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-28092.php). Si on vérifie la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4140) il n'y a pas cette possibilité non plus; le seul usage qui est reconnu est l'usage du conditionnel après « si » et l'imparfait. Un phrase correcte est la suivante.

> Je reste à votre disposition s'il faut des précisions.

Tous les cas prévu à la [présente référence](http://www.francenepal.info/article_view.php?id=4572) sont du type « **Je reste à votre disposition pour …**». Une alternative correcte est certainement la suivante.

> Je reste à votre disposition pour des précision.

Dans [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/je+reste+%C3%A0+votre+disposition.html) la même chose est répétée : utilisation presque unique de « Je reste à votre disposition pour …»; on y trouve cependant le cas suivant qui coïncide avec la règle du présent.

> Je reste à votre disposition si vous avez  des questions ou des suggestions.

Il semblerait que la construction utilisée par votre amis ne soit pas très courante.